# Add similar Dynamic rows in SQL Query Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, addition, distinct-values

I need to perform something similar like to this, the tag field will have Dynamically generated values.

```
Tag                     | Qty  | Price_Of_Unit
--------------------------------------------------
Jam Bottle 90ml         | 2    | $9
Jam Bottle 180ml        | 1    | $15
Jam Bottle 180ml        | 3    | $15
Jam Bottle 180ml        | 2    | $15
Jam Bottle 90ml         | 2    | $9
```

I want a query that returns something like this:

```
Tag                     | Qty  | Price_Of_Unit
--------------------------------------------------
Jam Bottle 90ml         | 4    | $9
Jam Bottle 180ml        | 6    | $15
```

The qty field is added while there are no repeated values for the tag field.

Not: The table has these fields from which i am generating this query

```
ID, Tag, QTY, Price_Of_Unit
```

If anyone can answer, I am desperate! 
Thanks In advance!
Bhashithe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want a group by?

```
SELECT
    Tag
    ,sum(QTY)
    ,sum(Price_Of_Unit)
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    Tag
```

This will "group" all rows with the same tag, the other columns are functions on the group of rows - here i have chosen sum which adds together all the QTY and Price_Of_Unit columns.

Group By:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/group-by-clause-HA001231482.aspx

you can do other "aggregate" functions instead of sum:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177686(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Worked like It should!!

Answer (score 0):

For each tag, you are looking to sum up the `Qty` while also showing the individual `Price_of_Unit`. You'll have to go about this in a little bit of a roundabout way:

```
select t.Tag, sq.TotalQty, t.Price_of_Unit
from YourTable as t
inner join (
  select Tag, sum(Qty) as TotalQty
  from YourTable
  group by Tag
) as sq
on t.Tag = sq.Tag
```

This is because when you use grouping, SQL needs to aggregate *every column* that's not explicitly grouped. So, after grouping by `Tag`, you need to aggregate `Qty` (in this case by the total quantity per tag). If you were to also include `Price_of_Unit` in the select query with the `group by` clause, you would need to also aggregate that, which @gordatron has done by totalling the unit price--which as you'll agree doesn't make sense.